# Why I cannot use the @azure/web-pubsub node package in a react code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, import

I import the following package in a react/webpack app:

```
import { WebPubSubServiceClient } from '@azure/web-pubsub'
```

When I invoke `WebPubSubServiceClient` as follows:

```
const connectionString = 'XXXXX'
const hubName = 'YYYY'
let serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient(connectionString, hubName)
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occured as follows:  TypeError: url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.URL is not a constructor
    at parseConnectionString (parseConnectionString.js:24)
    at new WebPubSubServiceClient (hubClient.js:31)
```

By looking at the code in the debugger —which is located in the Microsoft `@azure/web-pubsub` node package code—, I see the import URL is probably the issue:

```
import { AzureKeyCredential } from "@azure/core-auth";
import { URL } from "url";
export function parseConnectionString(conn) {
    let parsed = {};
    conn.split(";").forEach((i) => {
        const assignmentPos = i.indexOf("=");
        if (assignmentPos === -1)
            return;
        const key = i.substring(0, assignmentPos).toLowerCase();
        const value = i.substring(assignmentPos + 1);
        parsed[key] = value;
    });
    let endpointPart = parsed["endpoint"];
    if (!endpointPart)
        throw new TypeError("connection string missing endpoint");
    if (!endpointPart.startsWith("http")) {
        endpointPart = `https://${endpointPart}`;
    }
    const key = parsed["accesskey"];
    if (!key)
        throw new TypeError("connection string missing access key");
    const credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
    const port = parsed["port"];
  >>  const url = new URL(endpointPart); << the error comes from here
    url.port = port;
    const endpoint = url.toString();
    url.port = "";
    return { credential, endpoint };
}
//# sourceMappingURL=parseConnectionString.js.map
```

Regarding Webpack I use the following version:

```
"webpack": "^4.44.2",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
```

I must say that using the same code and module in a pure nodeJS works nice.
So I believe it is related to react?

What should I do?

Comment: are you using this lib as `url` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/url . it hasn't been updated in 6 years, and maybe it doesn't have default export.

Besides, what version of webpack do you use?

Comment: Microsoft @azure/web-pubsub makes use of 'url' package (where the issue is located is the Micorsoft code). and regarding Webpack I use:
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",

Comment: Regarding the default export: url is imported as non-default import: the code where the issue is located is there: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/web-pubsub/web-pubsub/src/parseConnectionString.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, running on react is hassle-free, provided one choose the right constructor.

So here is how to do it:

```
// == Azure WebPuSub
import { WebPubSubServiceClient, AzureKeyCredential } from '@azure/web-pubsub'

// == W3C sockets
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from 'websocket'




// == Create the service client
const hubName = 'telemetry'
const key = <KEY>
const cred = new AzureKeyCredential(key)
const endpoint = "https://XXXXX.webpubsub.azure.com"
const serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient(endpoint, cred, hubName)
console.log('Azure WebPubSub service client is', serviceClient)

/**
 * @summary Connect to the secure socket server thru the WebPubSub service
 */
async function connect ({onError, onOpen, onMessage, onClose}) {
    console.log('About to get auth token…')
    let token = await serviceClient.getAuthenticationToken()
    //console.log('Auth token is', token)
    
    // == Connect to the secured socket server          
    const url = token.url
    let wsClient = new W3CWebSocket(url)

    console.log('Web socket is',wsClient)


    // == Connect the callbacks
    wsClient.onerror = onError
    wsClient.onopen = onOpen
    wsClient.onmessage = onMessage
    wsClient.onclose = onClose
}

// == Now actually connect to the secure web sockets
connect({onError, onOpen, onMessage, onClose})
```

And voila! Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `@azure/web-pubsub` should've removed the "URL" dependency. Fixed with https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/pull/15300