# How to use Azure PubSub in React Native?

Tags: node.js, azure, react-native, websocket, azure-web-pubsub

I'm trying to build a chat app with React Native, and I'm trying to use Azure Web Pub Sub for that.
I'm following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-pub-sub-messages?tabs=javascript#set-up-the-subscriber) so I added [@azure/web-pubsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/web-pubsub) dependency to my project, and copied this piece of code that I found on the docs:

```js
// other react native imports...

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const { WebPubSubServiceClient } = require('@azure/web-pubsub');

async function main() {
  const hub = "pubsub";
  let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient(process.env.WebPubSubConnectionString, hub);
  let token = await service.getClientAccessToken();
  let ws = new WebSocket(token.url);
  ws.on('open', () => console.log('connected'));
  ws.on('message', data => console.log('Message received: %s', data));
}
```

I run the app on android and I get this error telling me that the [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) dependency cannot be found in these directories: **node_modules@azure\web-pubsub\node_modules**

Here's the full error from the console:

```bash
error: Error: Unable to resolve module url from C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\@azure\web-pubsub\dist\index.js: url could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\@azure\web-pubsub\node_modules
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\node_modules
  11 | var jwt = _interopDefault(require('jsonwebtoken'));
  12 | var logger$1 = require('@azure/logger');
> 13 | var url = require('url');
     |                    ^
  14 |
  15 | /*
  16 |  * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:158:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async addDependency (C:\Users\abdou\source\Mobile Apps\Test app\AwesomeTSProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
```

##### **So I'm asking is it not possible to use Azure Web PubSub service with React Native? Or should I just use the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package to communicate with the PubSub service? And if so how so?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I cannot use the @azure/web-pubsub node package in a react code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493059/why-i-cannot-use-the-azure-web-pubsub-node-package-in-a-react-code)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531338/15969115

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thanks for the comment unfortunately the answer does not help, I actually added the **url** dependency to my project and I got a different error, the @azure/web-pubsub library is using **jsonwebtoken** library which works only in a node environment so it's throwing dependency errors that work only in node such as **util**, **jws** and **data-stream**. So I'm wondering why they would use node packages in a library intended to run in the client? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I'm asking is not possible to use Azure Web PubSub service with React Native, or should I just use the ws package to communicate with the PubSub service? And if so how so?

According to [vicancy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webpubsub/issues/445):

- Since the React Native app is a pure WebSocket client, there is **no need for** it to use the `@azure/web-pubsub` package, just use the [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package to communicate to the service.
- It is not safe to store the connection string on the client side.
- The common way for the WebSocket client to get the URL to connect to Azure Web PubSub is similar to the workflow mentioned in step 2 of the sample: [Add/Negotiate an API to the server to generate the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-build-chat?tabs=javascript#create-the-application)

**Updated answer:**

According to [abdou-tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9566611/abdou-tech):

- There's no need for `@azure/web-pubsub`, the package is meant for Node clients who want to connect to the Azure PubSub service.

**Note:** The [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package also doesn't work in React Native or the browser it requires the Node runtime. You can use the native [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object to connect to the service

Comment: Yes that's right, there's no need for `@azure/web-pubsub`. The package is meant for Node clients who want to connect to the Azure PubSub service and not browser clients. **Note that the [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package also doesn't work in React Native or the browser it requires the Node runtime.** So for anyone looking, just use the native [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) object to connect to the service.